# Voting reversal is not correct

Tags: bug, serial-voting

Yesterday I was a victim of serial downvoting. I lost 12 reputation points as a result.

I waited however because I knew that it will be eventually reversed.

Today when the voting was corrected, I only got 8 points back.

Is there something wrong with voting reversal?

As you can see in the screenshot, I lost 12 points within the span of 120 seconds. But I believe that my reputation has not been corrected completely.

[image]

These are two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068553/multiplication-table-in-swift-ios/37068869#37068869) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561379/how-to-use-lgsidemenucontroller/37561686#37561686) for which voting has not been corrected.

It is possible that these two answers might not have been downvoted by the same guy (Hence the script did not correct their voting) but in that case I'd like a confirmation if that's not too much of a bother for our already busy mods.

Comment: Wouldn't help if you named them in public since you don't have concrete proof of it.  That said, the script is more conservative than not when rolling back downvotes, given that one or two *may* have been legitimate.

Comment: _"...2. If after 36 hours (give the script time to run) you still see a problem, then flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to look into the anomalous voting patterns.
3. If it still hasn't been corrected, contact the SE team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site."_ ([cross-site dupe at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28758/165773))